# safeboot and wubi

Tags: ubuntu, wubi, encryption

Having read various posts it seems clear that installing Wubi on a machine which already has safeboot installed with disk encryption is a non-starter at the moment - nor is repartitioning the disk it would seem.

However, as the `C:` partion is encrypted - it has an NTFS formatted `Q:` partition that is not encrypted and has about 4GB free - I was wondering if there was any way to install Wubi using that partition. Obviously, I still need a means of booting into it without stuffing my safeboot booting mechanism.

I'm thinking that this should be possible as the safeboot booting mechanism will get me to the boot choice options and thereafter all references in the `boot.ini` entry for the Wubi installation should be to files on the non-encrypted NTFS partition and so it should be OK and not attempt any changes to my encrypted `C:` partition (other than adding the extra entry to `boot.ini`)?

Comment: installing linux to a thumbdrive sounds like a way more workable solution here.

Answer (score 1):

Any machine with safeboot will *almost certainly* not be a personal machine but a business machine, no?
--> If you want Wubi for personal use, then consider putting it on a personal computer.

Any attempts to bypass the safeboot, or to install another OS, will *almost certainly* summon the wrath of your corporate security staff, no?
--> I would say: *don't* try it, and have the IT department provide a workable solution for you.

Comment: Where is the fun in that?

Answer (score 0):

I would say to try it and report back what happens as your own answer to the question. This should probably also be marked community wiki. Since I do not have anything like the setup you are talking about (and nobody else probably does either) you would probably need to try this and see what happens. Would be valuable information for someone else who is looking to do something similar.